# make existing object in array the last item in the array REDUX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, redux

I am fetching some data from Mongodb. THe data is an array of objects. I would like to make the object with group.title === "unsubscribers" the last object in the array always. the array will always have variable length.

I am using React with Redux and trying to push my object with title "unsubscribers" to the end of the array so I can always render as last item in a table

Here is my reducer. the console.log is showing me 3 not the array of objects

```
import { LIST_GROUPS, LIST_SHOW_GROUPS } from '../actions/types';


export default function (state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        // when we logout, this action.payload is an empty string so lets do || false 
        case LIST_GROUPS:
            const unSubGroup = action.payload.filter((group) => group.title === "unsubscribers")
            const allOtherGroups = action.payload.filter((group) => group.title !== "unsubscribers")[0]
            console.log(allOtherGroups.push(unSubGroup))
            return action.payload
        case LIST_SHOW_GROUPS:
            return action.payload.filter((el) => { return !el.hide })  
            default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, but `.push` returns the number of elements in the result, instead of the actual result, all you have to do is move the `console.log` one line down:

```
const unSubGroup = action.payload.filter((group) => group.title === "unsubscribers")
const allOtherGroups = action.payload.filter((group) => group.title !== "unsubscribers")[0]
allOtherGroups.push(unSubGroup)
console.log(allOtherGroups)
```

However, I think you should `return allOtherGroups` instead of `return action.payload`

Answer (score 0):

Yes my code was ALMOST CORRECT. I needed to add the brackets to unSubGroup to make sure and return the object instead of an array with an. object inside.

I was getting a result like this where the unSubGroup was an array with an object, I only wanted the object.

```
0: {contacts: Array(445), _id: '6266fa8df11e', title: 'presidential', created: '2022-04-25T19:46:21.792Z', hide: false}
1: {contacts: Array(0), _id: '626a0d61db63', title: 'rolex', hide: false, created: '2022-04-28T03:43:29.664Z'}
2: [{…}]
```

```
import { LIST_GROUPS, LIST_SHOW_GROUPS } from '../actions/types';


export default function (state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        // when we logout, this action.payload is an empty string so lets do || false 
        case LIST_GROUPS:
            const unSubGroup = action.payload.filter((group) => group.title === "unsubscribers")[0]
            const allOtherGroups = action.payload.filter((group) => group.title !== "unsubscribers")
            allOtherGroups.push(unSubGroup)
            console.log("allOtherGroup", allOtherGroups)
            return action.payload
        case LIST_SHOW_GROUPS:
            return action.payload.filter((el) => { return !el.hide })  
            default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

above function gave me below output ( needed to add the [0] to end of unSubGroup filter method

```
0: {contacts: Array(445), _id: '6266fa8df', title: 'presidential', created: '2022-04-25T19:46:21.792Z', hide: false}
1: {contacts: Array(0), _id: '626a0d61db', title: 'rolex', hide: false, created: '2022-04-28T03:43:29.664Z'}
2: {contacts: Array(0), _id: '626a0bc2', title: 'unsubscribers', hide: false, created: '2
```